# compare input to an object arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel, actionlistener, jtextfield

I would like to compare the input from a JTextField to all the elements in a string arraylist. If the input is equal to an element in the list I would like the program to acknowledge by saying "This is in my vocabulary.", and if it is not, I would like the program to say "This is NOT in my vocabulary." In my code, I have tried getting this to work buy I always get the message "This is NOT in my vocabulary." even if the input matches an element in my list. How can I get this to work properly?

Here is my code, in it AI is where the list that is being compared is.

```
package Important;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import AI.*;

public class TextActions implements ActionListener{

private String hero;
private Vocabulary vocab1 = new Vocabulary();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    e.getSource();
    hero = e.getActionCommand();

    if (vocab1.Adjectives.equals(hero)){
        System.out.println("This word is in my vocab");
    }else{
        System.out.println( hero + " is not in my vocab");
    }
    //CompareWords(hero);
}

public void CompareWords(String readme){

    if (vocab1.Adjectives.contains(readme)){
        //System.out.println("This word is in my vocab");
    }
}

}
```

Here is the Vocabulary class as requested.

```
package AI;
```

import java.util.*;

public class Vocabulary {

```
//String[] thoughts;
public List<String> Adjectives = new ArrayList<String>();


public void AddWord(int ArrayListNumber, String WordEntered){

    if(ArrayListNumber == 1){
    Adjectives.add(WordEntered);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your Vocabulary class?

Comment: Its seems like you are invoking equals on the entire list object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new object

```
Vocabulary vocab1 = new Vocabulary();
```

This would contain an empty Adjectives  list.
So, you have to first populate the Adjectives  list before you do the checking as follows

```
vocab1.Adjectives.contains(hero)
```

and use contains instead of equals.

Comment: Okay, I changed equals to contains and for some reason I still get the "This is Not in my vocabulary" message.

Comment: Can you share the Vocabulary class.

Comment: Make sure the vocabl.Adjectives is not empty. Because from the above code, for every action you are creating an new instance Vocabulary object and the Adjectives list must have been populated in the Vocabulary class

Comment: There isn't much to my Vocabulary class, it just has the list and an adder to add words to various vocabulary lists, but when my program starts up it adds various adjectives to the adjectives class, I interact with the program after this is done.

Comment: Cool. Since you have created new instance object for Vocabulary class in the TextActions class the Adjectives list would be empty unless you call the AddWord method to populate. 
Can you try this please. Just before you do the checking 
vocab1.Adjectives.equals(hero)
Can you do vocab1.AddWord(1, hero) and then check.

Comment: Ohhh! I understand now, even though the vocabulary class has the words added to it prior to input, the new instance I created does not. That is correct right?